# CSS Not Centering Container

Tags: css

I have a container div. Width: 80%, margin-left: 10% and margin-right 10%. The problem is, the container is displaying to the left in all the browsers I check. If I change the value of margin-left to 20%, it looks ok.

I will supply code if necessary but is there anything obviously wrong here? Isn't 80 with a margin of 10 on each side correct to center a div?

GF

Answer (score 2):

I tried your setup, and it works just fine.

You should check the spelling and syntax of your CSS, there is probably some error that keeps it from working. In Firefox you can open up the error console and reload your page, and it will tell you about any CSS errors.

You can also use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to center the element.

Here is the code of the page that I used to test the CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="sv" xml:lang="sv">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div { width: 80%; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%; background: #ccc; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>asdf</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try set theese:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 80%;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        Testing page
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem either. It's the same result as setting margin left and right at 10%.

Comment: Thanks. It was actually a HTML problem. I had included an extra div that wasn't required.Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

has the parent element of the div a specified witdh?

Try

```
width: 100%;
```

for the parent Element

Comment: I set the width of the body (the parent of the div) to 100% but it changes nothing still.